# How does the nested if and else statements work in the Flutter or dart?

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart

```dart
User _returnUserFromFirebase(FirebaseUser user) {
    if(user==null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return User(id:user.uid);
    }

}


Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async{
    GoogleSignIn _signIn = GoogleSignIn();
    GoogleSignInAccount _account= await _signIn.signIn();
    if(_account!=null){
      GoogleSignInAuthentication _authentication = await _account.authentication;
      if(_authentication.idToken!=null && _authentication.accessToken!=null){
        final AuthCredential _credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken:
        _authentication.idToken, accessToken: _authentication.accessToken);
        final AuthResult _authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(_credential);
        return _returnUserFromFirebase(_authResult.user);
      }
    }
  }
```

This function has a return type of 'Future', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'. What is the problem in this code? Is else necessary to add in this code after using two ifs? It is not even recognizing the return statement in the code.

Comment: `signInWithGoogle` has a `return` statement for one code path, but no `return` statements along the paths your `if` conditions aren't met.  A function with a return value must return a value (or throw an exception) along *all* paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `return null;` as a last line of `signInWithGoogle` method.

The compiler says you that if `_account!=null` condition is false (account is actually null) the function won't return anything because the code branch with `return` statement won't be executed.

Comment: that works but if I do this: else {return null;} why is it showing the same error as above? Isn't adding else same as what you said above? You just told me to add 'return null' .I added it at the end with else { return null;}, it is showing the same error as above

Comment: @MilanPoudel that's because you have `return` atatement inside nested `if`s there: `if(_account!=null){` and `if(_authentication.idToken!=null && _authentication.accessToken!=null){` inside it. In the case if the first condition is true and the second is false, you don't execute any branch having `return` statement, even though you've added `else` to the first statement.